# Tailwind CSS styles applied locally, but not when deployed on Render

Tags: reactjs, webpack, deployment, tailwind-css, render

I've deployed my portfolio on render.com but it isn't incorporating the Tailwind CSS that is reflected when I run it locally.

I'm a Tailwind CSS noob so any help would be greatly appreciated... I believe theres some sort of error with the path in terms of webpack bringing in the tailwind classes.

Here is my tailwind config file and my package.json respectively

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  important: true,
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is Mike Norris' portfolio to showcase his projects",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- --watch --mode=development",
    "test": "JWT=shhhhh mocha",
    "test:dev": "DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost/portfolio_db npm run test -- --watch",
    "test:dev:quiet": "QUIET=true npm run test:dev",
    "start:dev": "JWT=felix nodemon server/index.js --ignore dist/ --ignore src/ & npm run build:dev",
    "windows-start:dev": "nodemon server --ignore dist/ --ignore src/",
    "windows-dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run windows-start:dev\" \"npm run build:dev\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.12.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.12.1",
    "@nivo/core": "^0.83.0",
    "@nivo/line": "^0.83.0",
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.11.1",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.4.5",
    "react-swipeable-views-react-18-fix": "^0.14.1",
    "react-swipeable-views-utils": "^0.14.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.25.3",
    "ws": "^8.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@mui/system": "^5.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^9.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1",
    "mocha": "^10.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "supertest": "^6.3.1",
    "swiper": "^9.2.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/mjngit/portfolio"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mjngit/portfolio/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mjngit/portfolio#readme"
}
```

The github repo can be found here https://github.com/mjngit/portfolio

I've tried to change the webpack content to include CSS to see if that was the reason it wasn't reading the tailwind classes, nothing happened though. I've tried adding a style.css file to my src folder but that also did not change anything. I've crashed my build a few times trying to change the build commands to include tailwindcss.

Comment: what is  the build command you run at Render deployment

Comment: npm install && npm run build @HilaAveksis